# Does the All-Purpose Tool improve the save DC of the Artillerist artificer's "Explosive Cannon" detonation ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, saving-throw, artificer

At 9th level, an [Artillerist artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/artificer#Artillerist) gains the ability to detonate the cannon created by the 3rd-level **Eldritch Cannon** ability:

> Doing so destroys the cannon and forces each creature within 20 feet of it to make a Dexterity saving throw against your **spell save DC**, taking 3d8 force damage on a failed save or half as much damage on a successful one.

(Emphasis added.)

The [*all-purpose tool*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/all-purpose-tool) from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* grants a bonus, increasing with rarity, "to the spell attack rolls and the saving throw DCs of your ***artificer spells***." (Emphasis added.)

**Does the save DC bonus conferred by the *all-purpose tool* apply to the detonation of the cannon?** Is a bonus to the DC of spells logically the same as a bonus to spell save DC?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Eldritch Cannon is not an artificer spell.

This is pretty straightforward: the all-purpose tool increases the spell save DC for your artificer spells, and your Eldritch Cannon and all of its features are not artificer spells. So all-purpose tool will not affect the DC for your Eldritch Cannon.

A feature can increase your spell save DC without specifying it is only for your spells. For example, the robe of the archmagi states:

> Your spell save DC and spell attack bonus each increase by 2.

This increase your spell save DC *for all things that use your spell save DC*, since no particular use is specified. Compare this to the all-purpose tool:

> While holding this tool, you gain a bonus to the spell attack rolls and the saving throw DCs of your artificer spells.

The tool specifically only raises your spell save DC for your artificer spells, as opposed to raising it for all purposes, like the robe of the archmagi does for its wearer.

Comment: After a bit of thought, I agree, mainly because it uses the plural in "the saving throw DCs of your artificer spells", implying that the modifier applies to each spell as it is cast, rather than changing your spell save DC. However, this seems like such a weird hair for them to split that I have to wonder if it's intentional. At a quick glance, I think all the TCoE DC-increasing items use a similar wording.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson It's a hair they've been splitting for a long time, going all the way back to the Rod of the Pact Keeper and the Robe of the Archmagi, both appearing in the DMG, and both available to warlocks. A warlock can find herself with two magic items that boost spell save DC, where one boosts it for all purposes, and the other only for her warlock spells. So this construction is certainly not new to *Tasha's*.